# Can you limit a real variable between two bounds?

Tags: z3, z3py

Can you limit a real variable between two bounds?

```py
    s = Solver()
    input = Reals('input')
    s.add(input >= -2, input <= 2)
```

This example return `unsat` for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this, the `sexpr` method of the `Solver` class is your friend!

You're tripping up because of the extremely weakly typed nature of the z3py bindings. The call `Reals` returns multiple results, which you are assigning to a single element. That is, your `input` variable is now a list containing one variable. This, in turn, makes the whole program meaningless, as you can observe yourself:

```py
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
input = Reals('input')
s.add(input >= -2, input <= 2)
print s.sexpr()
```

This prints:

```
(assert true)
(assert false)
```

Why? Because your variable `input` is a list, and the bizarre rules of type promotion decided that a list is greater than or equal to `-2` but less than `2`. (This is totally meaningless, just the way the bindings work. There's no rhyme or reason it should be this way. One can argue it should do more type-checking and give you a proper error. But I digress.)

To solve, simply change your call of `Reals` to `Real`:

```py
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
input = Real('input')
s.add(input >= -2, input <= 2)
print s.sexpr()
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

This prints:

```
(declare-fun input () Real)
(assert (>= input (- 2.0)))
(assert (<= input 2.0))

sat
[input = 0]
```

which is exactly what you wanted to say.